# Reading in date from CSV into ts vector

Tags: r, date, csv

I am trying to read in a .csv file I got from yahoo and saved to my computer.  When I turn the data into a ts vector I want it to read in its own start and end dates.  The dates are in column A if you open the csv file in excel, with the newest date first in cell A2.

```
IBM <- read.csv("IBMMonthly.csv")  #reads in file

IBM <- subset(IBM, select = "Close")  #takes data from Close column only

IBM.ts <- ts(IBM, start = c(YYYY, MM), end = c(YYYY, MM), frequency = 12)
```

I need a code that will read in start date as the last cell in column A, and then then read in the end date as cell A2.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this issue entirely by using `read.zoo`:

```
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo("IBMMonthly.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE, FUN=as.yearmon, regular=TRUE)
```

Note that I tell `read.zoo` to coerce the index to `yearmon`, and that the series is regular.  This is important if you want to convert the result to `ts`.

Then extract the "Close" column and coerce to `ts`.

```
IBM <- as.ts(z[,"Close"])
```